# Can't Inject JPA API after Play 2.8 upgrade in Integration Tests (Scala)

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, sbt

So I am currently upgrading a project to Play 2.8 version, and I've managed to adapt Unit tests and the whole application to run the JPA API as requested in this new version, with Dependency Injection of the JPA API.

In my DBUnit Helper class, I had the following:

```
JPAApi jpaApi = Play.current().injector().instanceOf(JPAApi.class);
jpaApi.withTransaction((EntityManager em) -> {
// RUN QUERIES
};
```

How can I instantiate JPA API here? Or am I using dependency injection wrong?

With Play 2.8 this is no longer possible `Play.current().inject()`. I tried to Inject the dependency with Guice injector but without success.

Comment: That's Java, right? Not Scala.

Comment: Yep, you're right

Comment: Please check out my example which uses injection of jpaAPI https://github.com/ertra/play-framework-by-example/blob/master/app/dao/BookDAOImp.java , just inject it in the constructor   using   @Inject